# How to OR Django model field validators?

Tags: django, validation

Does anyone know how to OR together Django model field validators?

Something like this:

```
example_field = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[validator1|validator2])
```

I am guessing that there is a way and it involves the Q operator, but I can't find what it is exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the validation in a function itself:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

def combined_validator(value):
    try:
        return validator1(value)
    except ValidationError:
        return validator2(value)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    example_field = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        validators=[combined_validator]
    )
```

If `validator1` does not detect any trouble, then the control flow is returned, and thus we are safe. If it raises a `ValidationError`, then we fallback on `validator2`. If that does not raises an error, then we are again safe. Otherwise, the error will raise out of `combined_validator`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed an OR-validator as well, so I made a little reusable validator that
can accept any number of sub-validators that are OR-ed together.
Inspired by Django's own validators, so should work everywhere (only tested in Django Rest Framework serializer)

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator, RegexValidator
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from rest_framework import serializers

@deconstructible  # allows usage in migrations
class OrValidator:
    message = 'Enter a valid value.'  # customize this based on the sub-validators
    code = 'invalid'

    def __init__(self, validators, message=None, code=None):
        self.validators = validators
        self._errors = []
        if code is not None:
            self.code = code
        if message is not None:
            self.message = message

    def __call__(self, value):
        for validator in self.validators:
            try:
                return validator(value)
            except ValidationError as e:
                # save error for debugging
                self._errors.append(e)
        # non matched, raise error
        raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
            self.validators == other.validators and
            isinstance(other, self.__class__) and
            self.message == other.message and
            self.code == other.code
        )

class UsernameValidator(RegexValidator):
    regex = re.compile(r'^[-\w]+\Z', re.UNICODE)

# example usage in Django Rest Framework (should work in forms and models as well)

class ResetPasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email_or_username = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        validators=[
            OrValidator(
                [EmailValidator(), UsernameValidator()],
                message='Enter a valid email or username',
            ),
        ],
    )
```